Error using command to trigger extension's popup to open: Receiving end does not exist
I'm trying to build a chrome extension and all other functions from background.js are working fine, but the one that's supposed to use a keyboard shortcut command to open the extensions popup. All other answers point to the permissions on manifest.json and issues in the popup.js or corresponding js file.
Here's my manifest.json:
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Chrome extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "chrome extension",
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "dist/background.js"
  },
  "commands": {
    "searchTabs": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+Shift+F"
      },
      "description": "Open Tab Finder"
    }
  },
  "permissions": ["tabs", "commands"],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "public/popup.html"
  }
}


And here's my popup.js:
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener((port) => {
    port.onMessage.addListener((message) => {
        if (message.action === "searchTabs") {
            console.log("Search action triggered with searchText:", message.searchText);
        }
    });
});


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const port = chrome.runtime.connect({ name: "popup-script-connection" });

    port.onMessage.addListener((message) => {
        if (message.action === "openPopup") {
            document.getElementById("popupContent").style.display = "block";
        }
    });
});

function searchTabs() {
    var searchText = document.getElementById("searchText").value;

    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "searchTabs", searchText: searchText });
}


There is more code in popup.js but I don't think it's relevant for this discussion. From what I understand, my manifest has the correct permissions and my popup.js contains the correct function to be called or referenced to open the extension's popup.
I have tried using chrome.runtime.connect()/chrome.runtime.onConnect() and also chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener()/chrome.tabs.sendMessage(), but neither seem to be working.
From this I expect to be able to press Ctrl+Shift+F to open the extension's popup window in Chrome.
